# Does Cordova App with external JS file violate App Store Guidelines?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a cordova hybrid app for iOS. The app contain basic JS file. When the app loads, it will connect to the server and grab the latest main JS file and cache store into the user phone. The cached JS will always be used until new update of JS file available, then the app will automatically re-download the new JS file and load with it. Therefore, when user first install & run the app, they will first see the loading screen saying something like "Please wait, downloading update now".

So, does this kind of method violate Apple App store guidelines?

Comment: No, apple changed the agreement some time ago to allow code download on webview based apps, and cordova uses a webview, so you are good

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. If my app get approved, and in future I update my external JS file containing function that violate App Store Review Guidelines, will my app be banned and take down from app store?

Comment: If you violate the App Store Review Guidelines and they find out they will remove the app